# pandas: how to aggregate two list columns when joining data frames

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, outer-join

I have the following two data frames:

```
    id  websites
    --   ---
0   1   [cnn.com, bbc.com]
1   2   [ebay.com, facebook.com]

________________

    id  websites
    --   ---
0   2   [google.com, facebook.com]
1   3   [amazon.com, youtube.com]
```

I want to outer join them on the `id` column by aggregating unique `websites` for matched rows. The output should be as below:

```
    id  websites    
    --   ---
0   1   [cnn.com, bbc.com]  
1   2   [ebay.com, facebook.com, google.com]
2   3   [amazon.com, youtube.com]
```

I have tried the following so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2],'websites':[['cnn.com','bbc.com'],['ebay.com','facebook.com']]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'id':[2,3],'websites':[['google.com','facebook.com'],['amazon.com','youtube.com']]})
df_a.merge(df_b, on='id', how='outer')
```

which is giving me the following output:

```
    id  websites_x                 websites_y
    --   ---                        ---
0   1   [cnn.com, bbc.com]         NaN
1   2   [ebay.com, facebook.com]   [google.com, facebook.com]
2   3   NaN                        [amazon.com, youtube.com]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concat them and then groupby on `id` column:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2],'websites':[['cnn.com','bbc.com'],
                    ['ebay.com','facebook.com']]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'id':[2,3],'websites':[['google.com','facebook.com'],
                    ['amazon.com','youtube.com']]})
```

---

Solution:

**Method1:**

```
a = df_a.explode('websites') #requires pandas version 0.25+
b = df_b.explode('websites') #requires pandas version 0.25+
out = pd.concat((a,b)).groupby('id')['websites'].apply(pd.unique).reset_index()
#or out = pd.concat((a,b)).groupby('id')['websites'].agg(set).reset_index()
print(out)
```

**Method2:**

Another solution using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) which doesnot need the exploded dataframes:

```
from itertools import chain
out = (pd.concat((df_a,df_b)).groupby('id')['websites']
     .apply(lambda x : dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(x)).keys()).reset_index())
print (out)
```

---

```
   id                              websites
0   1                    [cnn.com, bbc.com]
1   2  [ebay.com, facebook.com, google.com]
2   3             [amazon.com, youtube.com]
```